# Table of Contents link to first section does not work correctly

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm trying to create links from my table of contents to the corresponding sections using **hyperref**.

However, I've noticed that if the first entry is an unnumbered section (`\section*`), the link just brings me to the table of contents.

Here's a small example to illustrate what I'm trying to say. Note that the second unnumbered section works while the first does not. Also, using a numbered section as the first entry would fix the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=black,
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered section 1}
\section*{Unnumbered section 1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered section 2}
\section*{Unnumbered section 2}

\end{document}
```

How can I have the first link so that it targets the correct page?

Answer (score 7):

I found out that using `\addcontentsline` just after `\section*` fixes the problem.

So the corrected code would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,
    linkcolor=black,
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section*{Unnumbered section 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered section 1}

\section*{Unnumbered section 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered section 2}

\end{document}
```

As pointed out by @daleif, you should add `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline` if you use hyperref.

So just like

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Name}
\section{Name}
```

Comment: @toekleyy remember `\phantomsection` right before `\addcontentsline`, the hyperlink needs something to grap hold of, normally it would here use the section counter, but it is not in use, so we need `\phantomsection` to help it.

Comment: @daleif ah I see. Adding `\phantomsection` fixed it, too. I wonder why it worked by just flipping the commands

Comment: @daleif do you want to post an own answer or should I just edit mine?

Comment: I don't hunt posts, so just update yours.

Comment: Leaving it there because I think it might help: it's probably better to put `\phantomsection` before the unnumbered section, so that when clicking on it, the hyperlink brings you **right above the section title**, instead of below it (which is a behaviour I found quite irritating ahah) :-)